# Delphi (XE6) : Array of Byte to TStringList

Tags: arrays, delphi, type-conversion, delphi-xe6, tstringlist

I have a function which returns a dynamic array of byte

```
type
  TMyEncrypt = Array of Byte;
  TMyDecrypt = Array of Byte;

function decrypt(original: TMyEncrypt) : TMyDecrypt;
```

The content of the returned dynamic array TMyDecrypt is a standard text with CRLF.

How can i load this into a TStringList with CRLF as separator, without saving it to a temporary file before?

EDIT: the retruned array of byte contains unicode coded characters

Comment: You'd need to know the text encoding

Comment: Hi David, just added as edit (unicode)

Comment: `StringList.Text := PChar(decrypt(MyEncrypt));` assuming byte array is in little endian order, and with proper null terminator.

Comment: That assumes the decrypted bytes are UTF-16, otherwise such a typecast will not work.

Comment: @Remy Since the question states that the data is encoded UTF-16, I don't think there's any need to assume anything

Comment: The question says "unicode coded" instead of "UTF-16 coded", and "unicode" does not always means UTF-16 to everyone. Better to be more explicit about the exact format.

Comment: @Remy On Windows that's usually what Unicode means. For instance `TEncoding.Unicode`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Decode the byte array to a string, and then assign to the `Text` property of the string list.

```
var
  Bytes: TBytes;
  StringList: TStringList;
....
StringList.Text := TEncoding.Unicode.GetString(Bytes);
```

Note the use of `TBytes` which is the standard type used to hold dynamic arrays of bytes. For compatibility reasons it makes sense to use `TBytes`. That way your data can be processed by other RTL and library code. A fact we immediately take advantage of by using `TEncoding`.

You could use `SetString`, as my answer originally suggested:

```
var
  Text: string;
  Bytes: TBytes;
  StringList: TStringList;
....
SetString(Text, PChar(Bytes), Length(Bytes) div SizeOf(Char)));
StringList.Text := Text;
```

Personally I prefer to use `TEncoding` because it is very explicit about the encoding being used.

If your text was null terminated then you could use:

```
StringList.Text := PChar(Bytes);
```

Again, I'd prefer to be explicit about the encoding. And I might be a little paranoid about my data somehow not being null terminated.

You might find that UTF-8 is a more efficient representation than UTF-16.

Comment: Thanks alot David... Problem is it's not in my "hands" about UTF-8 or UTF-16 since i'm not the creator of the files i "parse"

Comment: Note that I edited the answer to make it a little cleaner. I prefer TEncoding to the original SetString version.

Comment: @AndreasHinderberger: You have to know the encoding of the decrypted bytes in order to decode them correctly into a UTF-16 string for `TStringList` to consume.  If you don't know the byte encoding, you cannot decode the bytes.

Comment: @Remy We already did this. I said the same thing, and Andreas supplied the information.